# Showing that celling lg(n+1) = floor [lg n]+1

Tags: algorithms, induction

So im having a problem with the following:

Show that $\lceil lg(x+1)\rceil  = \lfloor lg x \rfloor +1$ for integers $x\ge 1$.

I started to show it by proving by induction, only problem was after showing x=1 holds true, then assuming x=n work, i went to the final step of trying to do $x=n+1$ and got stuck. Im not sure if im just simplifying it wrong or what but I cant seem to get it in any forms that are noticeably correct.

Comment: Which base are you using for logarithms?

Comment: The question did not state what to use. I assumed either base 2 or base 10.  Usually base 2 is represented lg, while base 10 is log.

Comment: Why did you delete the content of the question?

Comment: I am not sure why it is gone? Either it happened by mistake, or a friend on my computer did it, ill fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You need to consider four cases:

1. $x=1$.
2. $x=2^k$ for some $k\ge 1$.
3. $2^k<x<2^{k+1}-1$ for some $k\ge 2$.
4. $x=2^k-1$ for some $k\ge 2$.

In each case you can calculate $\lceil\lg(x+1)\rceil$ and $\lfloor\lg x\rfloor+1$, either explicitly or in terms of $k$, and compare them. Use the fact that if $k<y<k+1$, then $\lfloor y\rfloor=k$ and $\lceil y\rceil=k+1$. I’ll get you started.

1. $\lceil\lg(x+1)\rceil=\lceil\lg 2\rceil=\lceil 1\rceil$; what’s $\lfloor\lg x\rfloor+1$?
2. Then $2^k<x+1<2^{k+1}$, so $k<\lg(x+1)<k+1$, while $\lg x=k$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m=\lfloor \log_{2} x \rfloor$, so $m\le \log_{2} x<m+1$ and $2^m\le x<2^{m+1}$.

Then $2^m<x+1\le2^{m+1}$ since $x$ is an integer, so $m<\log_{2} (x+1)\le m+1$.

Therefore $\lceil \log_{2} (x+1)\rceil=m+1=\lfloor \log_{2} x \rfloor+1$.